# Conditional probability question about wording

Tags: probability

You play a series of independent games against an opponent. You win any game with probability $p$ and lose it with probability $q = 1 − p$. The ultimate winner is the first player to achieve a lead of two games. What is the probability that you will be the ultimate winner?

Hint: condition on the outcomes of the first two games and derive an equation for the unknown probability.

I am having trouble understanding what the question is asking. I don't understand how someone would win.

Comment: If the same player wins the first two games, they get a two-game lead so they win. If not, you play two more games, and again if one player wins both of those, they win overall. And so on.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime So it has to be that you win two consecutive games?

Comment: yes, in order to get two games ahead (having not been two games ahead previously), you have to have won the last two games.

Comment: They also have to be two consecutive games where the second one is even (e.g. games 3 and 4 would work, but games 4 and 5 wouldn't).

Comment: You win the match with an overall score of $2-0$ or $3-1$ or $4-2$ etc.  and lose with the reverse scores $0-2$ or $1-3$ or $2-4$ etc., at which time you stop playing.  And you keep on playing for at least another two games when the score reaches $0-0$ or $1-1$ or $2-2$ or $3-3$ etc.